# ReactSortable - prevent duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working my way through the ReactSortable examples (react-sortablejs), but I cant figure out how to prevent adding duplicate objects when cloning from one list to another:

```
    const [state, setState] = useState([
        { id: 0, name: "shrek", ...defs },
        { id: 1, name: "fiona", ...defs }
    ]);

    const [state2, setState2] = useState([
    ]);


...

 <div>
            <ReactSortable
                group={{ name: "cloning-group-name", pull: "clone" ,  put: false }}
                animation={200}
                delayOnTouchStart={true}
                delay={2}
                list={state}
                setList={setState}
                clone={item => ({ ...item })}
                sort= {false}
            >
                {state.map(item => (
                    <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
                ))}
            </ReactSortable>


            <ReactSortable
                // here they are!
                group={{ name: "cloning-group-name"}}
                delayOnTouchStart={true}
                delay={2}
                list={state2}
                setList={setState2}
                onAdd = { }
            >
                {state2.map(item => (
                    <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
                ))}
            </ReactSortable>
```

I've been trying to use the onAdd, but I just can't figure out the logic.  Thanks in advance.